# SonarQube create profile from web service

Tags: web-services, sonarqube

How and which web service can I call to create a new profile in SonarQube?

I've checked both `api/profiles` and `api/qualityprofiles` but could not find it. I am using Sonarqube 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, but this web service will definitely be created when we work on the redesign of the Quality Profiles page.

You can watch and vote for the following ticket: [SONAR-5851](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5851)